# Why does Updating Location of ArcSDE Feature using ArcObjects .NET give Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from call to COM component?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, c#, enterprise-geodatabase, geolocation

I have been able to connect to an Enterprise GeoDatabase, retrieve features from it and update attributes. However I am having problems accessing and then updating the shape property of a feature. Here is my code (its not production, just test code at the moment) :

```
  try
        {

            IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
            queryFilter.SubFields = "OBJECTID, Definitive_ID, FL_Id, GIS_ID, SAP_ID, CHECK_Status, CHECK_DateAbandoned, CHECK_Outfall_Ipid, CHECK_Outfall_X";
            queryFilter.WhereClause = "FL_Id = 71444";
            IFeatureClass testFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("SDE_CSO.DBO.DefinitiveList");

            IQueryFilterDefinition queryFilterDef = (IQueryFilterDefinition)queryFilter;
            queryFilterDef.PostfixClause = "ORDER BY OBJECTID";

            int nameIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("OBJECTID");
            int defIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("Definitive_ID");
            int flIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("FL_Id");
            int GISIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("GIS_ID");
            int sapIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("SAP_ID");
            int checkStatusIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("CHECK_Status");
            int checkDateAbandonedIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("CHECK_DateAbandoned");
            int checkOutfallIPIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("CHECK_Outfall_Ipid");
            int checkOutfallXIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("CHECK_Outfall_X");
            int XLatIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("XLat");
            int LongIndex = testFeatureClass.FindField("Long");

            using (ComReleaser comReleaser = new ComReleaser())
            {
                IFeatureCursor cursor = testFeatureClass.Search(queryFilter, true);
                comReleaser.ManageLifetime(cursor);
                IFeature feature = null;
                while ((feature = cursor.NextFeature()) != null)
                {
                    int ObjectID = Convert.ToInt32(feature.get_Value(nameIndex));
                    string Definitive_ID = Convert.ToString(feature.get_Value(defIndex));
                    int FL_ID = Convert.ToInt32(feature.get_Value(flIndex));
                    string GIS_ID = Convert.ToString(feature.get_Value(GISIndex));
                    string SAP_ID = Convert.ToString(feature.get_Value(sapIndex));
                    string CHECK_Status = Convert.ToString(feature.get_Value(checkStatusIndex));
                    string CHECK_DateAbandonedIndex = Convert.ToString(feature.get_Value(checkDateAbandonedIndex));
                    string CHECK_OutfallIPID = Convert.ToString(feature.get_Value(checkOutfallIPIndex));
                    string CHECK_OutfallX = Convert.ToString(feature.get_Value(checkOutfallXIndex));
                    double XLat = Convert.ToDouble(feature.get_Value(XLatIndex));
                    double Long = Convert.ToDouble(feature.get_Value(LongIndex));

                    Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriGeometry.SpatialReferenceEnvironment");
                    System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
                    ISpatialReferenceFactory3 spacialReferenceFactory3 = obj as ISpatialReferenceFactory3;
                    IGeoTransformation geoTrans = spacialReferenceFactory3.CreateGeoTransformation((int)esriSRGeoTransformationType.esriSRGeoTransformation_OSGB1936_To_WGS1984Petrol) as IGeoTransformation;
                    ISpatialReference fromSpatialReference;
                    ISpatialReference toSpatialReference;
                    geoTrans.GetSpatialReferences(out fromSpatialReference, out toSpatialReference);

                    var wgs84GCS = spacialReferenceFactory3.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984);
                    var bngPCS = spacialReferenceFactory3.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRProjCSType.esriSRProjCS_BritishNationalGrid);

                    IGeometry geometry = feature.ShapeCopy;
                    IPoint point = geometry as IPoint;
                    point.PutCoords(-3.159875, 51.465615);
                    geometry = point as IGeometry5;
                    geometry.SpatialReference = wgs84GCS;
                    point = new PointClass();
                    point = geometry as PointClass;
                    point.SpatialReference = wgs84GCS;

                    feature.Shape = point;
                    feature.Store();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("Problem Connecting to Feature Class or Querying : " + ex.Message);
        }
```

I am using an IQueryFilter which I thought would allow me to update the feature, however I get an error at the line "IGeometry geomtey = feature.ShapeCopy" - "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

I am probably doing something incorrectly, please could someone advise how to change the location of an existing Point Feature using C# ArcObjects .NET (Im using v10.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused because the "Shape" field must be specified in the edit query. I assumed (obviously foolishly) that the Geometry of a feature point would automatically be part of the query - its not.

Comment: +1 I coulda sworn this wasn't needed in earlier versions.

Comment: It may depend on whether the underlying DBMS is SDE, file GDB, etc.